# What is the fastest way to get the result of an Entity Framework query into a DataTable?

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, entity-framework, entity-framework-5

I have reviewed many answers, However, I believe it should be easier than looping the results or rebinding and using `SqlDataAdapters`.

Performance is important in my case,

What is the fastest way to get the following query in a `DataTable` in C# Or VB.Net where `econtext` is a `DbContext`?

```
Dim r = (From AdCustomProperties In econtext.AdCustomProperties
         Where AdCustomProperties.AdID = AdID
         Select AdCustomProperties.PropertyTitle2, AdCustomProperties.PropertyValue2)
```

Comment: `Entities` were not meant to be returning `DataTables`.

Comment: Why do you need it to fill a `DataTable`? You can do binding on the `Entities`.

Comment: I have another query returning results from another database, and i would like to concat the results of both but i can't because the first  is returning System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable and the second is returning System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbQuery, Performance is important so i think that having both queries in a DataTable is faster than casting.

Comment: Can you show us your query structure?

Comment: Could you add that to your question - you can format it better in there?

Comment: @DonA, for the current question let's assume that the second data i have it in the form of DataTable, so i definitely need an answer to get EF query in the form of DataTable.

Comment: @DonA, I have added another question regarding the problem that drove me to ask for a data table, I would really appreciate your help [HERE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20788129/combine-two-ef-queries-unable-to-cast-object-of-type-system-data-entity-infrast)

Comment: You still don't necessarily need to get it into a DataTable. You could use "LINQ to DataSet" and join the two sources in memory.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're seriously that concerned about squeezing out the last ounce of performance and need a faster way of getting data into a data table and not bound to the entity, you should consider using ADO.NET instead of EF.

Comment: Or, indeed, something like Dapper.